# reserving private ip range

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

OpenVPN normally uses the private IP range of 10.8.0.0/24. If I wanted to create a vpc of 10.8.0.0/16, How can I prevent the DNS (or is it the DHCP) server for assigning addresses out of OenVPN's  range?

So far I can only see creating subnets around that range and only put instances in those subnets, not in the parent VPC range. (Which may not even be possible anyways)?

Comment: "So far I can only see creating subnets around that range and only put instances in those subnets, not in the parent VPC range." Given that instances *have* to be in a subnet, this seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: I have no experience with Amazon services. Is the addressing you've given specific to this service? Do you have full control over your OpenVPN installation, or is it Amazon managed? If former, you should probably go another way - routing or bridging.

Comment: Yes, the range and base can be chosen. But eventually, given a large site, or accessing from lots of other networks around the world, or some mistake by a future employee, there could be collision. I'm trying to understand how my own site can avoid using that range, (or any range chosen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon VPC's network infrastructure assumes that all of the address space in the supernet associated with the VPC will be *inside* the VPC, associated with instance interfaces.  Your VPN, being on the "other side" of one instance, isn't "inside" the VPC.

As such, you *can't* provision your VPN to use any subnet within the VPC's address block, if you want your VPN to work, because the VPC route tables will not accept the static route that you'd need, in order for traffic bound for the VPN to be routable from any instance other than the one that hosts the VPN.  The routes for all subnets within the VPC's supernet are only ever implicit; explicit routes aren't accepted if they conflict, and a route to a subnet in the VPC's address space always conflicts.

10.8.0.0/16 includes 10.8.0.0/24 so that will not work.  If your VPC is 10.8.0.0/16, your VPN would need to be something else, non-overlapping, like 10.10.10.0/24.  Then you'd add a static route in the VPC route table, routing that subnet to the instance ID of the instance that functions as the VPN server.

So an inadvertent conflict is pretty much impossible, by the nature of the design of the VPC network infrastructure.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and acceptance. Went through some health issues and work has been intense.